# Getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError on larger files

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to send a large file to my server, but an error appears: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 268435468 byte allocation with 33554432 free bytes and 100MB until OOM`. Although if I try with small files then all works well.

This is my code:

```
public static byte[] getBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        int len = 0;
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }

        return byteBuffer.toByteArray();


}
```

**uploading function**

```
public static void uploadPDF(final String pdfname, Uri pdffile, String title, String photo, Context context, String ids){
        InputStream iStream;
        try {
            iStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(pdffile);
            assert iStream != null;
            final byte[] inputData = getBytes(iStream);

            VolleyMultipartRequest volleyMultipartRequest = new VolleyMultipartRequest(Request.Method.POST, upload_URL,
                    response -> {
                        rQueue.getCache().clear();
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(new String(response.data));

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    },
                    error -> Toast.makeText(context, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()) {

                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("ids", ids);
                    params.put("title", title);
                    params.put("photo", photo);
                    return params;
                }

                @Override
                protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() {
                    Map<String, DataPart> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("filename", new DataPart(pdfname ,inputData));
                    return params;
                }
            };


            volleyMultipartRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                    0,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
            rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
            rQueue.add(volleyMultipartRequest);



        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

---

```
public class VolleyMultipartRequest extends Request<NetworkResponse> {

    private final String twoHyphens = "--";
    private final String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    private final String boundary = "apiclient-" + System.currentTimeMillis();

    private Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> mListener;
    private Response.ErrorListener mErrorListener;
    private Map<String, String> mHeaders;


    public VolleyMultipartRequest(int method, String url,
                                  Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> listener,
                                  Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, errorListener);
        this.mListener = listener;
        this.mErrorListener = errorListener;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        return (mHeaders != null) ? mHeaders : super.getHeaders();
    }

    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);

        try {
            // populate text payload
            Map<String, String> params = getParams();
            if (params != null && params.size() > 0) {
                textParse(dos, params, getParamsEncoding());
            }

            // populate data byte payload
            Map<String, DataPart> data = getByteData();
            if (data != null && data.size() > 0) {
                dataParse(dos, data);
            }

            // close multipart form data after text and file data
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            return bos.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Custom method handle data payload.
     *
     * @return Map data part label with data byte
     * @throws AuthFailureError
     */
    protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() throws AuthFailureError {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<NetworkResponse> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            return Response.success(
                    response,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        mListener.onResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    public void deliverError(VolleyError error) {
        mErrorListener.onErrorResponse(error);
    }

    /**
     * Parse string map into data output stream by key and value.
     *
     * @param dataOutputStream data output stream handle string parsing
     * @param params           string inputs collection
     * @param encoding         encode the inputs, default UTF-8
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void textParse(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, Map<String, String> params, String encoding) throws IOException {
        try {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                buildTextPart(dataOutputStream, entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Encoding not supported: " + encoding, uee);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Parse data into data output stream.
     *
     * @param dataOutputStream data output stream handle file attachment
     * @param data             loop through data
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void dataParse(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, Map<String, DataPart> data) throws IOException {
        for (Map.Entry<String, DataPart> entry : data.entrySet()) {
            buildDataPart(dataOutputStream, entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Write string data into header and data output stream.
     *
     * @param dataOutputStream data output stream handle string parsing
     * @param parameterName    name of input
     * @param parameterValue   value of input
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void buildTextPart(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, String parameterName, String parameterValue) throws IOException {
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + parameterName + "\"" + lineEnd);
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(parameterValue + lineEnd);
    }

    /**
     * Write data file into header and data output stream.
     *
     * @param dataOutputStream data output stream handle data parsing
     * @param dataFile         data byte as DataPart from collection
     * @param inputName        name of data input
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void buildDataPart(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, DataPart dataFile, String inputName) throws IOException {
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" +
                inputName + "\"; filename=\"" + dataFile.getFileName() + "\"" + lineEnd);
        if (dataFile.getType() != null && !dataFile.getType().trim().isEmpty()) {
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: " + dataFile.getType() + lineEnd);
        }
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        ByteArrayInputStream fileInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(dataFile.getContent());
        int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

        int maxBufferSize = 1024 * 1024;
        int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            dataOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    }

    public class DataPart {
        private String fileName;
        private byte[] content;
        private String type;

        public DataPart() {
        }

        public DataPart(String name, byte[] data) {
            fileName = name;
            content = data;
        }

        String getFileName() {
            return fileName;
        }

        byte[] getContent() {
            return content;
        }

        String getType() {
            return type;
        }

    }
}
```

An error occurs on this line:

```
  byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
```

Comment: You are not going to be able to read large files into memory, as you will run out of memory. You will need to use some other option, such as a streaming `RequestBody` with OkHttp.

Comment: You are trying to read the entire contents of something very big (over 200mb) into memory. Of course eventually you'll run out of memory. Why are you doing this, what do you do with the results?

Comment: @Joni I have increased the content of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input sream gives you too much data to keep it in RAM.

#### Option 1:

Process the data while reading the file(in the loop)

#### Option 2:

Save it to a file and process it from the file without loading the whole content to your RAM.

You can jump back and forth in the file.

---

The `OutOfMemoryError` says that you tried to allocate data on the heap but your application didn't have enough free RAM to use. On 32-Bit devices(that lots of phones are), it can also mean that you ran out of addressable space.

It occured while writing to the `ByteArrayOutputStream` because a `ByteArrayOutoutStream` stores it's content(the byte array) in the heap and it could not allocate enough space to increase the size of the internal byte array.

Answer (score 0):

[You cannot use Volley](https://github.com/google/volley/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions) for this:

> ### Why doesn't Volley support large downloads/uploads?
>
> Volley is not suitable for large download or streaming operations, since Volley holds all requests and responses in memory during parsing.

You'll have to use another HTTP client. Pretty much any HTTP client other than Volley supports large downloads and uploads. Personally I prefer OkHttp, but if you prefer not to add yet another library dependency you can make do with [`HttpUrlConnection`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection) even though it's cumbersome. Just search for "how to upload file with X on android" where X is the http client you choose to use.